# Выборка из списка Python последовательно

Tags: python, list

Хочу получить из словаря списков

```
d = {
    'hi': [('qw', 86), ('er', 23)], 
    'bye': [('hgd', 20), ('sa', 945), ('nd', 83)],
    'do': [('as', 27), ('ds', 46)],
} 


for k, v in d.items():
    if k in ['hi', 'bye']:
        r = l[N] - нужен только один уникальный список из списка списков ниже. Или же может прям из d можно такое сгенерировать. Здесь должен быть [('qw', 86), ('hqd', 20)], в следующем цикле [('qw', 86), ('sa', 945)] и т.д.
    else:
        r = random.sample(v, 2)
```

Возможно надо сформировать сперва список из d для hi & bye, а потом последовательно брать по одной строке. Либо эту последовательность можно создавать и брать сразу в цикле, но как тогда узнать об уникальности данной строки.

```
l = [
    [('qw', 86), ('hqd', 20)],
    [('qw', 86), ('sa', 945)], 
    [('qw', 86), ('nd', 83)],
    закончились варианты с первым список продолжается
    [('er', 23), ('hqd', 20)],
    [('er', 23), ('sa', 945)],
    [('er', 23), ('nd', 583)],
    закончились варианты с первым список продолжается
    [('hgd', 20), ('sa', 945)],
    [('hgd', 20), ('nd', 83)],
    и т.д.
]
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Откуда чего брать? Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Хотя бы из списка [1,2,3,4,5] сделать [(1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (1,5), (2,3), (2,4), (2,5), (3,4), (3,5), (4,5)]. То есть все возможные значения первых двуз чисел, потом со вторым числом и т.д.

Comment: Может вам, кстати, функция `itertools.permutations` пригодится. Она возвращает все перестановки данного итерируемого объекта.

Comment: @Глеб спасибо за мысль, мне нужна была itertools.combinations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну можно например вот так, только исходный словарь `d` вам нужно обработать таким образом, чтобы в нём оставались только те элементы, которые вам нужны.

```
d = {
    'hi': [('qw', 86), ('er', 23)], 
    'bye': [('hgd', 20), ('sa', 945), ('nd', 83)]
}

l = []

for key1, value1 in d.items():
    for key2, value2 in d.items():
        if key1 != key2:  # Убедимся, что мы не объединяем одинаковые ключи
            for item1 in value1:
                for item2 in value2:
                    l.append([item1, item2])


for sublist in l: # Просто для красивого вывода
    print(', '.join([f"('{x}', {y})" for x, y in sublist]))
```

Вывод:

```
('qw', 86), ('hgd', 20)
('qw', 86), ('sa', 945)
('qw', 86), ('nd', 83)
('er', 23), ('hgd', 20)
('er', 23), ('sa', 945)
('er', 23), ('nd', 83)
('hgd', 20), ('qw', 86)
('hgd', 20), ('er', 23)
('sa', 945), ('qw', 86)
('sa', 945), ('er', 23)
('nd', 83), ('qw', 86)
('nd', 83), ('er', 23)
```

---

UPD

Нашёл более привлекательное решение, используя `itertools`, так как вам нужны именно КОМБИНАЦИИ а не все возможные перестановки:

```
d = {
    'hi': [('qw', 86), ('er', 23)], 
    'bye': [('hgd', 20), ('sa', 945), ('nd', 83)]
}

combined_list = [item for sublist in d.values() for item in sublist]

# print(combined_list) # мы соединяем два ключа вместе образуя один массив

from itertools import combinations

result_list = list(combinations(combined_list, 2)) #смотрим комбинации через itertools

for i in result_list:
    print(i)
```

Вывод:

```
(('qw', 86), ('er', 23))
(('qw', 86), ('hgd', 20))
(('qw', 86), ('sa', 945))
(('qw', 86), ('nd', 83))
(('er', 23), ('hgd', 20))
(('er', 23), ('sa', 945))
(('er', 23), ('nd', 83))
(('hgd', 20), ('sa', 945))
(('hgd', 20), ('nd', 83))
(('sa', 945), ('nd', 83))
```

Comment: Отлично, почти то что надо. Еще бы не включать такие варианты [('nd', 83), ('qw', 86)], те что были, то есть ('qw', 86) уже было в самом начале

Comment: @kisean обновил ответ

Comment: Вместо `combined_list = [item for sublist in d.values() for item in sublist]` можно использовать `itertools.chain.from_iterable(d.values())`.

Comment: ... исходный *лист d* ...?

Comment: @wchistow упс, словарь же...